# Regex in Java: Capturing string up to a certain group of words

Tags: java, regex, string

I'm trying to capture a string up until a certain word that is within some group of words.

I only want to capture the string up until the FIRST instance of one of these words, as they may appear many times in the string.

For example:

Group of words: (*was, in, for*)

String = "Once upon a time there *was* a fox *in* a hole";
would return "Once upon a time there"

Thank you

Comment: Also, there may or may not be a period after one of our "capturing" words. eg using the group above:

String "The fox did not realize what it *was.*"

would return "The fox did not realize what it"

Comment: can you just do a couple of `indexOf`s and trim the string beforehand, and then run your regex? (if this is a common problem you could make that a function)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you need is called a [Lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).  The exact regex for your situation is:

```
/^.+?(?=(?:was)|(?:in)|(?:for))/
```

Anyway, the ^ matches the beginning of the string, .+? is a lazy match(it will match the shortest possible string), (?= ... ) means "followed by" and (?: ... ) is a noncapturing group - which may or may not be necessary for you.

For bonus points, you should probably be using word boundaries to make sure you're matching the whole word, instead of a substring ("The fox wasn't" would return "The fox "), and a leading space in the lookahead to kill the trailing space in the match:

```
/^.+?(?=\s*\b(?:was)|(?:in)|(?:for)\b)/
```

Where \s* matches any amount of white space (including none at all) and \b matches the beginning or end of a word.  It's a Zero-Width assertion, meaning it doesn't match an actual character.

Or, in Java:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^.+?(?=\\s*\\b(?:was)|(?:in)|(?:for)\\b)");
```

I think that will work.  I haven't used it, but according to the documentation, that exact string should work.  Just had to escape all the backslashes.

### Edit

Here I am, more than a year later, and I just realized the regex above does not do what I thought it did at the time.  Alternation has the highest precedence, rather than the lowest, so this pattern is more correctly:

/^.+?(?=\s*\b(?:was|in|for)\b)/

Compare this [new regex](http://regexr.com?371uc) to my [old one.](http://regexr.com?371uf)  Additionally, future travelers, you may wish to capture the whole string if no such breaker word exists.  Try THIS on for size:

```
/^(?:(?!\s*\b(?:was|in|for)\b).)*/
```

This one uses a NEGATIVE lookahead (which asserts a match that fails the pattern).  It's possibly slower, but it still does the job.  [See it in action here](http://regexr.com?371uo).

Comment: Great! And will this enforce that there's a space before the word and possibly a period after it?

Edit: Also how does Java formatting differ?

Comment: The second one will, yes.  There could be any manner of punctuation or space after the key word, and any manner of space before it and it will still match.

Comment: Added an answer to your Pattern question.

Answer (score 5):

You can use this code to capture the string before a terminating word:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^(.*?)((\\b(was|in|for)\\b)|$)");
String s = "Once upon a time there was a fox in a hole";
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

This code produces the following output ([link](http://ideone.com/Lrt5h)):

```
Once upon a time there
```

Here is how this expression works: the `(\\b(was|in|for)\\b)` means "any of the words listed in the inner parentheses, when they appear on word boundaries". The expression just outside allows for `$` in order to capture something even if none of the terminating words appear in the source.

Comment: I'm voting for your answer, because it is functional, but your terminology is wrong.  You're capturing both groups and only returning the first, rather than using a non-capturing groups.

Comment: @FrankieTheKneeMan Thanks! This was from before the first edit, when I was using a non-capturing group. Pshemo pointed out that my non-capturing group was not necessary, so I deleted it, but I forgot to fix the wording.

Answer (score 3):

A very simple way to handle this is to just `split` the string with a regex and keep the first thing returned:

```
String str = "Once upon a time there was a fox in a hole";
String match = str.split("(was|in|for)")[0];

// match = "Once upon a time there "
```

In this example, `match` will either contain the first part of the string *before* the first matched word or, in the case of a string where the word wasn't found it will contain the entire string.

Comment: This is actually a significantly better answer than mine.

Answer (score 2):

```
String s = "Once upon a time there was a fox in the hole";
String[] taboo = {"was", "in", "for"} ;
for (int i = 0; i < taboo.length; i++){
    if (s.indexOf(taboo[i]) > -1 ){
        s=s.substring(0, s.indexOf(taboo[i])) ;
    }
}
out.print(s);
```

works on my computer..

Comment: After looking at all the other answers I feel like mine is the least elegant.

Comment: "I feel like mine is the least elegant" Yet is is very likely the fastest one, assuming a small number of `taboo` words. +1